# Trivial tkinter button works on Python 3.5, initially unresponsive on Python 3.6, 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

On Python 3.6 and 3.7 on MacOS 10.12.6, a `tkinter.Button` does not initially respond to clicks - but the same code works perfectly on Python 3.5.

If I run the following script:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Button')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

then on Python 3.6 and 3.7, a window appears with a single button as expected, it does not visually appear to be disabled, but clicking on it has no effect.

Resizing the window or clicking elsewhere within it does not fix the issue. 
 However, if I bring another application to the foreground and then bring the Python application back to the front, everything works perfectly, and I am then unable to make the issue reappear.

In Python 3.5, running the test script brings up the application and the button is immediately responsive to clicks - as expected.  Experimentation was unable to reproduce any issues in 3.5.  The script also runs fine in Python 2.7 if `tkinter` is replaced by `Tkinter`.

Changing the `pack` layout manager to `grid` gave exactly the same results.

I went so far as to reboot the machine, with no change.

I am close to 100% certain that the Python 3.6 and Python 3.7 binaries and libraries are in a good state.  They are essentially clean installs as I work entirely in virtualenvs. And my non-trivial `tkinter` application runs identically on Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7, except for this one problem.

Comment: Okay, but what's your question? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: change your line to this: `button = tk.Button(root, text='Button', command=lambda:print('Hello!'))`, this will test if button really works

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I think the OSX version of tkinter is a little buggy.

Comment: @AndriiChumakov : I just edited the code to do that explicit test, and it works in the tiny test too.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I'm sorry if this is unclear - I'd like to figure out my code doesn't work on all versions of Python, and either if there's a bug in my code, or if there's some workaround, or a bug in MacOS.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I wondered about that, but I found no one else with similar issues.  Surely I can't be the first one to ever use this on MacOS?

Comment: @Tom you are not the 1st to use it on mac. That is why Bryan is saying its a bit buggy on OSX. Because others have had problems. I wonder if doing `root.update_idletasks()` right before you create the button may fix the problem. I know there are some focus issues in tkinter it will fix so its worth giving it a try here.

Comment: @mike-smt : A++.  If I add a call  `root.update_idletasks()` _both_ before _and_ after the `button.pack()` command, then the problem goes away.  If I comment out either of those calls the problem persists, but I don't really care.  If you want to actually answer the question, I'll give you the win!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have a Mac to test on but your issue sounds very similar to a focus problem that can occur on windows when you open a file dialog before the mainloop has had its first complete loop. The issue has the same symptoms like not allow focus to get back to the window until you bring up some other app and then go back to the tkinter app and then it works.

The way to correct the focus issue is to apply `root.update_idletasks()` before the problem (IE. right before opening the file dialog) and in this case right before your button.

As the OP has pointed out they had to add the `root.update_idletasks()` before and after the widget and I am not sure why this was the fix here for OSX. For those reading this with the same issue on Mac go ahead and try this option for a work around.

Comment: This fixes the problem.  Note that I had to call `root.update_idletasks()` twice - once before and once after packing the button.  Neither single call on its own worked!

Comment: @TomSwirly that may just be part of the buggy issues with OSX. I have not had a chance to really work with python on Mac so I cannot say for sure why. I am glad that this little work around was the trick here.

Comment: @TomSwirly you said you added the update before and after the `pack()` have you tried just adding it right before you define the button?

Comment: In fact, I added that line in all three places - before creating the button, before packing and after packing - and tried all eight combinations to make sure.

Comment: I like to be systematic, it's just easier.  Thanks for getting me out of a jam.